# scp execution fails when when executed from a script after udev rule trigger - Script works if executed manually or through cron

Tags: bash, scp, udev

Good evening
I have set proxmox server on an old laptop , where I run a couple of VM's. I created an udev rule to copy a file (uevent) from host (Proxmox) to one of the VM's (home assistant) when  the power is disconnected
The problem I'm running into is that when udev executes the script the scp line times out.

ssh from host to vm works fine and I can even run the scp command manually:

```
/usr/bin/scp -v /root/uevent1.json root@192.168.7.48:/root/config/BAT1
```

I also can run the script that udev is supposed to execute and works fine (batupdate1.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
FILE=/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent
awk -F'=' 'BEGIN {printf "{"} /POWER_SUPPLY/  {printf "\"" $1 "\":\"" $2 "\","} END {print "}"}'  $FILE | sed 's/,}/}/' >/root/uevent1.json
/usr/bin/scp -v /root/uevent1.json root@192.168.7.48:/root/config/BAT1
```

udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh"
```

This is how the syslog looks like for this particular script:

```
: ADP1: RUN '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh' /etc/udev/rules.d/80-local.rules:2
: Starting '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'
: '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'(err) 'Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.7.48, user root, command scp -v -t /root/config/BAT1'
: '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'(err) 'OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019'
: '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'(err) 'debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config'
: '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'(err) 'debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config'
: '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'(err) 'debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *'
: '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'(err) 'debug1: Connecting to 192.168.7.48 [192.168.7.48] port 22.'
: Spawned process '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh' [30840] is taking longer than 59s to complete
: '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'(err) 'debug1: connect to address 192.168.7.48 port 22: Connection timed out'
: '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'(err) 'ssh: connect to host 192.168.7.48 port 22: Connection timed out'
: '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh'(err) 'lost connection'
: Process '/usr/local/bin/batupdate1.sh' failed with exit code 1.
```

I have tried everything, started and restarted udev service , the whole server and nothing seems to make scp work from a script when called from a udev trigger

Any help will be enormously appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: What user did you test this with and what user does the your script run as (i.e. id > /tmp/id.log)?  I.e. confirming both are root. My guess is that your udev script doesn't have the capability (permission) to make network requests.  Just for the fun of it, does it work manually if you run the command via `at now`?  If so, does it work if you run it from udev with `at now`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166849/18-04-how-can-udev-rule-run-script-access-network seems to suggest that the above is on the right track: "Note that running programs that access the network or mount/unmount filesystems is not allowed inside of udev rules, due to the default sandbox that is enforced on systemd-udevd.service."

Comment: Hi Allan,  the process uses root to run the script. If manually executed via `at now` it also works however It fails if used inside udev rule so I think you are right, scp  (network command) is not allowed in udev triggers

Answer (score 0):

Per `man udev(7)`: "Note that running programs that access the network or mount/unmount filesystems is not allowed inside of udev rules, due to the default sandbox that is enforced on systemd-udevd.service".

The configuration file that implements that restriction appears to be `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service`:

```
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_NETLINK AF_INET AF_INET6
```